# How to display data from ksqlDB in UI?

Tags: ksqldb

How to display data from ksqlDB in UI?

I use Angular app, and I am wondering how to display real time data in web interface or mobile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ksqlDB has a [Restful API](https://docs.ksqldb.io/en/latest/developer-guide/api/) you can talk to. However, it may be worth waiting for the upcoming 0.10 release as that will come with a new client API, which will be easier to work with from JS.

Comment: Ksqldb is it part of kafka or separate d db? So, how using this api to get data in UI? Polling Api?

Comment: Totally depends what you're trying to achieve. I'd recommend looking at installing the free confluent platform to get yourself a working environment with everything you need to run ksqlDB. Then head over to https://ksqldb.io/ to get started.

Comment: Ineed for example to show users positions on the map

Comment: Where did you get that info? "0.10 will come with a new client api"? Mind sharing?